# Does the auth.log changes when I update?

Tags: updates, log

As always, I have been using the Software Updater to search and install my updates.

I know that the syslog and the dpkg.log changes when I update my system, but the auth.log also changes? Since it uses a high privilege action, it should appear.

Strangely, today after updating, it didn't appeared. Now I'm not sure if it really changes.

Thank you guys for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Look at what has changed in the log file:  `sudo tail /var/log/auth.log` - it is just a text file, after, all.